# How to append bunch of option to select tag in HTML using prototype js

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

How to append bunch of option to select tag in HTML using  prototype js.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With a reference to the select tag:

```
var select = $('my_select_tag_id');
```

Iterate over your options in a hash:

```
$H({foo: 'bar', boo: 'baz'}).each(function(pair){
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(pair.value, pair.key);
});
```

It is important that you don't try to just shove the values into the option as if they were HTML elements, using `select.insert('<option value="foo">bar</option>')` or similar, because that won't work in all browsers. jQuery does something fancy to work around this, because that's precisely the way they would have you do it.